# Angular2: router-outle for each module

Tags: angular, typescript

I have angular app having multiple modules (modules A, B are lazy loaded):

**MainModule, ModuleA, ModuleB**

Currently all content is loaded in AppComponent (it have router-outle tag). What I would like to achive is that I will have:

**AppComponent, ComponetA, ComponentB**

each having **router-outle** each module will have content in its own component. Thanks for any sugestions how to achive that.

Comment: Here is a working stackblitz example that might help. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yh3yci

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give you the "simplified" main structure that you need with 2 levels (main level (**forRoot**), and other modules level loaded by "Lazy loading" (**forChild**), ok?).
You always can make it more complex, adding **guards**, **more nested levels**, etc.

So, it would be something like that (you have to change to your own components):

1. **MainModule** (app-module.ts)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
 
import { AppComponent } from './components/App.component';
import { PageAComponent} from './modules/module-a/components/page-a.component';
import { PageBComponent} from './modules/module-b/components/page-b.component';
 
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent ,
  },
  {
    path: 'patha', 
    component: PageAComponent,
    children: [{
      path: '',
      loadChildren: () => import('./modules/module-a/module-a.module').then(m => m.AModule)
    }],
    },
{
    path: 'pathb', 
    component: PageBComponent,
    children: [{
      path: '',
      loadChildren: () => import('./modules/module-b/module-b.module').then(m => m.BModule)
    }],    
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '',
  },
];
 
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

2. **AModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { PageAComponent } from './pages/page-a/page-a.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/register/register.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', // takes the "base path" defined in its parent routes (in app.module.ts)
    component: PageAComponent, 
    pathMatch: 'full', 
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login', // For instance
        component: LoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'register', // For instance
        component: RegisterComponent,
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        // component:LoginComponent
        redirectTo: 'login',
      },
    ],
  },
];
 
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AModule { }
```

3. **BModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { PageBComponent } from './pages/page-b/page-b.component';
import { ListComponent} from './components/list/register.component';
import { EditComponent} from './components/edit/edit.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', , // takes the "base path" defined in its parent routes (in app.module.ts)
    component: PageBComponent, 
    pathMatch: 'full', 
    children: [
      {
        path: 'list', // For instance
        component: ListComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'edit', // For instance
        component: EditComponent,
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        // component:LoginComponent
        redirectTo: 'list',
      },
    ],
  },
];
 
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class BModule { }
```

4. In the **AppComponent** you would have your main < router-outlet>< / router-outlet>
5. Then, in **PageAComponent** and **PageBComponent** you would have only < router-outlet>< / router-outlet> as well.
   (You can think in pages kind a components that only serve to have the < router-outlet> in its html, ascting as a "containers" for the child module components).

That's all. For sure you have to "tune up" name's components/paths/modules to suit your own, but you have the structure and the sugestions that you were asking for.